# Não consigo printar um array com foreach

Tags: php, array, foreach

Não consigo printar meu array quando coloco uma chave diferente, dá o erro Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(),  como prosseguir?

```
for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) { 
        $use[$i]['outrachave'] = 'some valor';
    for ($j=0; $j < 2 ; $j++) { 

        for ($k=0; $k < 2 ; $k++) { 
            $use[$i][$j][$k]= 'z';
        }
    }
}


foreach ($use as $key) {
    echo "<br/>";
    foreach ($key as $a) {

        echo('<br>');
        foreach ($a as $b) {
            print_r($b);
            echo('<br>');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O que esta tentando fazer afinal? Porque tanto `for` e `foreach`?

Comment: Estou fazendo uma tabela de usuarios com um array Usuario que tem varias chaves  




Assim 
           $usuario['id_usuario']['nome']
           $usuario['id_usuario']['cargo']
           $usuario['id_usuario']['relacao']['avaliado']
           $usuario['id_usuario']['relacao']['avaliou']
           $usuario['id_usuario']['relacao']['avalio']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta retornando o erro:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

porque você esta tentando iterar um elemento que não é array:

```
$use[$i]['outrachave'] = 'some valor';
```

Para resolver, você pode fazer uma condição e verificar se o elemento é um array:

```
if ( is_array($a) ){
  foreach ($a as $b) {
    print_r($b);
    echo "\n";
  }
} else {
  echo "Valor do elemento 'outrachave': {$a}\n";
}
```

#### Código completo

```
$use = [];
for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) { 
  $use[$i]['outrachave'] = 'some valor';
  for ($j=0; $j < 2 ; $j++) { 
    for ($k=0; $k < 2 ; $k++) { 
      $use[$i][$j][$k]= 'z';
    }
  }
}

foreach ($use as $key) {
  echo "\n";
  foreach ($key as $a) {
    if ( is_array($a) ) {
      foreach ($a as $b) {
        print_r($b);
        echo "\n";
      }
    } else {
      echo "Valor do elemento 'outrachave': {$a}\n";
    }
  }
}
```

#### Referência

- [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-array.php)

[Pode ver funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/@wellmotta/308748-ptstackoverflow)